# Sets $S$ such that no difference of two distinct elements is divisble by a square

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

In this [paper](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Egasarch/TOPICS/vdw/sqdiff-ruzsa.pdf), Ruzsa shows that for $n$ sufficiently large, there exists a set $S$ of size $\Omega (n^{0.733})$ such that for all $a,b\in S$, the number $a-b$ is not a square. I am wondering about a stronger result. Namely, I want to find a set $S$ such that for all $a,b\in S$ we have that $a-b$ is square-free, that is, not divisible by any square.

On the first page of the paper, Ruzsa claims that if the set of numbers below $n$ to be avoided is $Q(n)$ (in our case the numbers divisible by squares), then there is a $S$ of size $\geq n/2|Q(n)|$ such that no difference produces an element in $Q(n)$. Now, it has been shown that the square free numbers have asymptotic density not more than $1/2$. But this together with Ruzsa's remark is not strong enough to make $S$ larger than constant size.

Are there any results known that allow us to build an $S = \Omega(n^{\epsilon})$ for some absolute $\epsilon > 0$ such that the differences of $S$ are all square--free? Perhaps we can transform the set $S$ with no perfect square as a difference to the desired set?

Comment: I think you forgot to say that $S$ is a subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S = \{1,6,11,16\}$ is a set with $|S| = 4$ with the property that the difference of any two distinct elements is not divisible by a square (the differences are $5$, $10$, and $15$.

If $|S| > 4$, then, by the pigeonhole principle, two elements are congruent modulo $4$. Their difference will then be divisible by $4$ and thus not squarefree.

Comment: Very nice, thanks for (somewhat disappointing) but succint answer :)